# Google Sheets - Compare a cell against two other columns, return non-match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This one is easy in theory, hard to execute (for me, anyway...:))

***BEFORE***

| Key Value | Column A | Column B | Missing Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith, D | Jones, E | Smith, D |  |
| Todd, L | Todd, L | Booth, R |  |

***AFTER***

| Key Value | Column A | Column B | Missing Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith, D | Jones, E | Smith, D | Jones, E |
| Todd, L | Todd, L | Booth, R | Booth, R |

I have the first three columns of static data. I need to compare the Key Value against Col A and Col B and put whichever value from Col A or Col B doesn't match the Key Value in the Missing Value column.

Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,B2:B,C2:C,lambda(a,b,c,ifna(textjoin(char(10),1,filter({b,c},{b,c}<>a)))))
```

- *`row_4` (in screenshot) depicts a scenario(if it even exists) when there's no match in either of the columns*

[image]

Comment: Nice! I was wondering what I'd do in the scenario where the key value matches neither. Very much appreciated.

Comment: You can try using this [table generator](https://tableconvert.com/html-to-markdown) for ease of updating the tables in a post here

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you want to populate the "Missing Value" column with the value from either Column A or Column B, whichever doesn't match the "Key Value." You can achieve this using Google Sheet's formulas. Here's how you can do it step by step:

Assuming your "BEFORE" table is in columns A to D, and your "AFTER" table is in columns F to I:

1. In cell F1 (the header of "Missing Value" in the "AFTER" table), write "Missing Value" or any desired header.
2. In cell G2 (below the header "Key Value" in the "AFTER" table), enter the following formula:

   ```
   =IF(A2=B2, "", IF(A2=C2, B2, A2))
   ```

   This formula compares the "Key Value" (cell A2) with both "Column A" (cell B2) and "Column B" (cell C2). If they match, it returns an empty string. If "Key Value" doesn't match "Column A," it returns the value from "Column A." If it doesn't match "Column B," it returns the value from "Column B."
3. Drag the formula in cell G2 down for all the rows where you have data.
4. Your "AFTER" table in columns F to I should now display the values with the "Missing Value" populated as you described.

Remember that you might need to adjust cell references (A2, B2, C2) based on the actual row you are working with. Also, be sure to adjust column letters (A, B, C) if your data is in different columns.

This approach uses the IF function to compare values and populate the "Missing Value" accordingly. It's a common way to solve such data transformation tasks in Google Sheets.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, that's close. I should have clarified, the values in Col B and Col C could be in any order. The formula you gave appears to only work if the matching value is in Col C.

I didn't explain my issue very well. Col A will be a set value, and I need to compare it against Col B and Col C. It's a given that only one of the columns will have a match. However, the matching value may be in Col B, or it may be in Col C. Either way, I need Col D to display which value doesn't match Col A.

I tried =IF(A3=B3, C3, IF(A3=C3, B3 )) and it seems to work, I will keep testing!